# Hide the Recent Documents List inside Ribbon Application Menu in Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, ribbon-control

I am using Delphi 2010 to implement an Application Menu for my ribbon control... but there is a recent documents list (or at least the title of it) on the right hand side of it...

Is it possible to hide this list and put something else there instead, like I am thinking of a list of available functions...

Will this violate the term of use of the ribbon control?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change TRibbon.ApplicationMenu.Caption property to change the caption of that list, and you can also change TRibbon.ApplicationMenu.CommandType to "ctCommands" to provide a list of your favorite commands rather than Recent Documents.

Comment: I've tried changing the command to ctCommands but somehow is still appear as a recent list... don't know why?

Comment: It works fine for me, just change the CommandType to ctCommands, then add your commands to TRibbon.ApplicationMenu.Menu.RecentItems. They will be listed as commands in Recent Documents list.